# R: data.frame will not accept row input and changes my variables into N/A values

Tags: r

New to R. I'm trying to read in excel file names and populate a data.frame:

Let's say I've already read in a file name

```
counter <- 1 #simplifying as this would be a for loop that would start with a counter at 1
file_name <- "excel file name"
 extension <- "xlsx"
 status <-"successful"
```

I initialize the data.frame and label the columns

```
global_file_list <- data.frame(File.Name = as.character(),
                                Extension = as.character(),
                                Status = as.character())
```

When I try to populate this first row, I get the following warnings and the data.frame populates with N/A's:

```
global_file_list[counter,] <- data.frame(cbind(file_name, extension, status))

Warning messages:
1: In [<-.factor(*tmp*, iseq, value = c(file_name = 1L)) :<br>
invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In [<-.factor(*tmp*, iseq, value = c(file_ext = 1L)) :<br>
invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In [<-.factor(*tmp*, iseq, value = c(status = 1L)) :<br>
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

However, if I were to do the following, without using the counter, the first row populates:

```
global_file_list <- data.frame(cbind(file_name, extension, status))
```

Then this continues to work but still populates with N/A values

```
counter <- counter + 1
 global_file_list[counter,] <- data.frame(cbind(file_name, extension, status))
```

1. What is the reason the dataframe won't accept the first entry with a counter?
2. Why does it populate with N/A instead of my variable values?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `global_file_list` was create using factors instead of vectors of character.
You can use `strengAsFactors = FALSE`

```
global_file_list <- data.frame(File.Name = as.character(),
                               Extension = as.character(),
                               Status = as.character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


global_file_list[counter,] <- cbind(file_name, extension, status)
```

Comment: That solved it!  For others reading this, the two items Marcelo's code pointed out that I was doing incorrectly were: 1) use stringsAsFactors during the initialization of the data.frame, not when attempting to input data into it (as I had tried that as well), and 2) there is no need to input the data to global_file_list by using the "data.frame" command again as I was doing "data.frame(cbind(..."  It works with just the cbind.  Thanks again!